# SSH remote execution - How to declare a variable inside EOF block (Bash script)

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following code in a bash script:

```
    remote_home=/home/folder
    dump_file=$remote_home/my_database_`date +%F_%X`.sql
    aws_pem=$HOME/my_key.pem
    aws_host=user@host
    local_folder=$HOME/db_bk
    pwd_stg=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    pwd_prod=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
    ssh -i $aws_pem $aws_host << EOF
    mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --result-file=$dump_file -u user -p$pwd_prod -h $db_to_bk my_database
    mysql -u user -p$pwd_prod -h $db_to_bk -N -e 'SHOW TABLES from my_database' > $remote_home/test.txt
    sh -c 'cat test.txt | while read i ; do mysql -u user -p$pwd_prod -h $db_to_bk -D my_database --tee=$remote_home/rows.txt -e "SELECT COUNT(*) as $i FROM $i" ; done'
EOF
```

My loop while is not working because "i" variable is becoming empty. May anyone give me a hand, please? I would like to understand how to handle data in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local shell is "expanding" all of the `$variable` references in the here-document, but AIUI you want `$i` to be passed through to the remote shell and expanded there. To do this, escape (with a backslash) the `$` characters you don't want the local shell to expand. I think it'll look like this:

```
ssh -i $aws_pem $aws_host << EOF
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --result-file=$dump_file -u user -p$pwd_prod -h $db_to_bk my_database
mysql -u user -p$pwd_prod -h $db_to_bk -N -e 'SHOW TABLES from my_database' > $remote_home/test.txt
sh -c 'cat test.txt | while read i ; do mysql -u user -p$pwd_prod -h $db_to_bk -D my_database --tee=$remote_home/rows.txt -e "SELECT COUNT(*) as \$i FROM \$i" ; done'
EOF
```

You can test this by replacing the `ssh -i $aws_pem $aws_host` command with just `cat`, so it prints the here-document as it'll be passed to the `ssh` command (i.e. after the local shell has done its parsing and expansions, but before the remote shell has done its). You should see most of the variables replaced by their values (because those have to happen locally, where those variables are defined) but `$i` passed literally so the remote shell can expand it.

BTW, you should double-quote almost all of your variable references (e.g. `ssh -i "$aws_pem" "$aws_host"`) to prevent weird parsing problems; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point this out for the local commands (along with some other potential problems), but you should fix it for the remote commands as well (except `$i`, since that's already double-quoted as part of the `SELECT` command).

Comment: Hi Gordon Davisson. Thanks a lot for your answer (very clear. Now I understand how to handle this kind of situation)...It was the solution for my issue. BTW: https://shellcheck.net is a very cool and useful tool, thanks for sharing it. Regards...